# Javascript to toggle class of image toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a js newbie (I am a graphic designer, not a coder). I need a toggle button to use within an application. I unfortunately cannot use CSS3 as it does not work in the app (I could have done this on my own with a pure CSS3 toggle button) so I decided to use images for the toggle button. I created a rollover image of the toggle button with the ON state on top and the Off state beneath. I am then using CSS to position and hide the Off state, then I created a new class with :hover to move the Off state image up to replace the On state. This is commonly used to create a simple rollover effect and I can do this easily, however I need it to switch when clicked, not hovered. This is where js is needed.

I also have a hidden checkbox (#optionsAutoClean) that I need to be checked when the toggle is ON and unchecked when the toggle is OFF.

I also need to be able to default the toggle to OFF on some, and ON on the other.

Any help would be appreciated. Again, I do not know much JS at all.

Below is my code and link to jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a id="btnAutoClean" class="toggleBtn" title="On/Off"></a>
  <input id="optionsAutoClean" disabled="disabled" class="toggleChk" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toggleBtn {
    display: block;
    width: 57px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image:url('http://techtalk.pcpitstop.com/wp-content/uploads/toggle.png');
}
.toggleBtn:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.toggleBtn_Off {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
}
.toggleBtn_On {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.toggleChk {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript: (I took a stab at this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggleBtn").removeClass(".toggleBtn_Off").addClass(".toggleBtn_On");
    $(".toggleBtn").removeClass(".toggleBtn_On").addClass(".toggleBtn_Off");
   });
});
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dd8v3wgb/1/

Comment: Why have two classes (`.toggleBtn_Off` and `.toggleBtn_On`), just one will suffice (the othe one will b the default state)! Here I made `.toggleBtn_on` the default state https://jsfiddle.net/g065ua2n/! That the first part of your question! Can you please clarify the rest!

Comment: The bit of code you have written uses jQuery. For this to work in JSFiddle you need to have jQuery selected under 'FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS' in the settings menu. And in your own application folder you need to have the jQuery library installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in plain javascript, and assuming you will end up with several buttons to switch rather than just one, you can do this by adding a toggle function to the event listeners for each button.  ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8p1c92f/3/))

```
function toggle(button) {
  return function() {
    button.classList.toggle('toggleBtn_Off');
    button.classList.toggle('toggleBtn_On');

    // assuming the input is the next element after the button
    button.nextElementSibling.checked = button.classList.contains('toggleBtn_On');
  }
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleBtn');

// Set defaults
buttons[0].classList.add('toggleBtn_Off'); // default off
buttons[1].classList.add('toggleBtn_On'); // default on

// Set event listeners to toggle each button and the hidden input next to it
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggle(buttons[i]));
}
```

```js
function toggle(button) {
  return function() {
    button.classList.toggle('toggleBtn_Off');
    button.classList.toggle('toggleBtn_On');

    // assuming the input is the next element after the button
    button.nextElementSibling.checked = button.classList.contains('toggleBtn_On');
  }
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleBtn');

// Set defaults
buttons[0].classList.add('toggleBtn_Off'); // default off
buttons[1].classList.add('toggleBtn_On'); // default on

// Set event listeners to toggle each button and the hidden input next to it
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggle(buttons[i]));
}
```

```css
.toggleBtn {
  display: block;
  width: 57px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('http://techtalk.pcpitstop.com/wp-content/uploads/toggle.png');
}

.toggleBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggleBtn_Off {
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}

.toggleBtn_On {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.toggleChk {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="btnAutoClean" class="toggleBtn" title="On/Off"></a>
  <input id="optionsAutoClean" disabled="disabled" class="toggleChk" type="checkbox">
  <a id="someOtherButton" class="toggleBtn" title="On/Off"></a>
  <input id="optionsAutoClean" disabled="disabled" class="toggleChk" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

`classList` is not available in older browsers so use this [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Polyfill) if you need to support them.

Comment: Stuart. You are awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Quick question, how can I make the default on state have the checkbox true by default when the page loads? Your code looks to work perfectly when the buttons are clicked, but it looks like by default when the page loads the ON state button does not have the checkbox checked. I commented out the css that is hiding the checkbox to test, and the checkbox is not checked for the ON state button by default. Thanks again man. This is great.

Comment: I guess an easy way around this is to simply add the "checked" attribute to the  input ids that will default to the On button position.

Comment: You could expand the toggle function into separate `switchOn` and `switchOff` functions which would also make sure the input boxes also get checked 
 / unchecked at the beginning https://jsfiddle.net/p8p1c92f/9/

Comment: Stuart, thank you again. Since I am still learning js, can you explain how the two buttons in the jsfiddle are being identified as default on and default off? How does it know the default on is set to be checked and the default off is not checked? I will have approximately 16 of these toggle buttons on a page, and maybe 7 of them need to be set to a default stage of OFF while the others will be ON. I assumed that by default, each button I add will have a default OFF because the checkbox would not be true by default. I could then add the "checked" attribute for the buttons I need to be ON.

Comment: In the JSFiddle in my comment: At the start of the script, the buttons are neither on nor off because neither class `toggleBtn_Off` not `toggleBtn_On` has been applied. The invisible checkboxes are unchecked. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of all of the elements with the class `toggleBtn` on the page, in order of appearance. So `buttons[0]` is the first one and `buttons[1]` is the second. We then explicitly switch them on or off. The switch functions change both the button appearance and the hidden checkbox.

Comment: A different way of doing this, as per @ibrahimmahrir's comment, is to have only one class `toggleBtn_On`, and set the defaults in the HTML, which simplifies the javascript a bit - like this https://jsfiddle.net/9n9Lqv8k/2/

Comment: Thanks Stuart. So, to identify them as the default state I need them to be when the page loads, I can simply add the toggleBtn_On or toggleBtn_off classes to the <a> elements so they will load as I need them to be. I think this will work. Tahnks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery - not javascript ;-)

You're missing the .click() in your jQuery statement:

```
$('.yourClass').click(function()
{
...
}
```

You could also try toggleClass:

```
$(".toggleBtn").toggleClass("toggleBtn_On toggleBtn_Off");
```

Try this:

```
$('.toggleBtn').click(function()
{
     $('.toggleBtn').toggleClass("toggleBtn_On toggleBtn_Off"); //Adds 'toggleBtn_On', removes 'toggleBtn_Off' and vice versa
});
```

Comment: Did you try it? It won't work if both classes are missing!

Comment: You're right! I should read the questions more carefully :-)
I guess having separate statements is what he has to use... including the click event.